# Ошибка в сортировке массива слов C++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Имеется массив char с 14k **русских** слов. Необходимо отсортировать этот массив по алфавиту. Готовые решения (например, **qsort()**) использовать нельзя. Решил сам реализовать алгоритм быстрой сортировки. И возникла проблема в том, что массив **сортируется не до конца**. Т.е. в результате, например, сначала идут слова на букву **'а'**, потом на букву **'б'**, а затем снова на **'а'**. И не могу понять, в чем **ошибка** / **недоработка**

Вот основной код:

```cpp
const int N = 14000; // Количество слов
const int M = 30;    // Максимальное количество букв в слове

char words[N][M];    // Массив слов

int compare(const char *arg1, const char *arg2)
{
   int i = _strcmpi(arg1, arg2);

   // Решение проблем с букой ё при сортировке
   if ((i >= 40 && i <= 45) || (i <= -40 && i >= -45)) 
       i *= -1; 

   return i;
}

void sort(int begin, int end)
{
    char* m = words[(begin + end) / 2];
    int l = begin;
    int r = end;
    char temp[M];

    while (l <= r)
    {
        while (compare(words[l], m) < 0) l++;

        while (compare(words[r], m) > 0) r--;

        if (l <= r)
        {
            strcpy_s(temp, words[l]);
            strcpy_s(words[l], words[r]);
            strcpy_s(words[r], temp);
            l++;
            r--;
        }
    }

    if (l < end)
        sort(l, end);
    if (begin < r)
        sort(begin, r);
} 

int main()
{
    /*
        Считывание слов из файла
        ...
    */

    sort(0, N-1)
}
```

Comment: "Готовые решения (например, qsort()) использовать нельзя." - по какой причине, простите?

Comment: Эта сортировка - часть курсового проекта.
И преподаватель обязал реализовывать алгоритм самому

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я понял, в чём была проблема. Для получения **серединного** (опорного) элемента, мы использовали **указатель** на этот самый элемент. Но во время работы алгоритма значение опорного элемента **может меняться**.

Решением проблемы стала замена этого участка кода

```
char* m = words[(begin + end) / 2];
```

На этот

```
char m[M];
strcpy_s(m, mas[(begin + end) / 2]);
```

Спасибо всем, кто думал над моим вопросом.